# How to name recorded file from AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avaudiorecorder

I am making an iOS app where I need to record speech using AVAudioRecorder and then I want to rename the file. Right now, I can successfully record the speech but I don't know how to give the file a custom name. How can I give the recorded file a custom name? Any help is appreciated.

In the `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
```

and all the other methods:

```
- (IBAction)recordPressed:(id)sender {
    if (!recorder.recording) {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        // Start recording
        [recorder record];
        NSLog(@"Recording...");

    } else {
        // Pause recording
        [recorder pause];
        NSLog(@"Paused...");
    }
}

- (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender {
    [recorder stop];
    NSLog(@"Stopped...");

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Show your code where you setup the `AVAudioRecorder` to record to a file.

Comment: I don't get the question. All you need to do is change `outputFileURL` to be the desired file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple move your file to another path, when you do that, you can specify a new name for the file, is the exactly same behavior of the `mv` command in shell.

There is a very simple snippet to you understand how to rename your file using move the `FileManager moveItemAtPath:toPath:error` method:

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *newPath = [docsDir  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newname.m4a"];

    // Try to move your file and the current path to newPath
    if ([fileManager moveItemAtPath:currentPath toPath:newPath error:&error] != YES)
    {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
      // File moved success
    }
```

Comment: Better yet, pass the proper URL to the `AVAudioRecorder` to start with. No need to move anything.